# Visual Studio CentralPackageVersionManagement Failed to restore due to "NuGet preview feature"

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

Getting this error in the latest update of Visual Studio.  We are using Central Packages, but I'm trying to figure out how to enable the preview feature to get it to build.    Maybe a setting I'm missing somewhere?

```
The project Test.csproj is using CentralPackageVersionManagement, a NuGet preview feature.
Failed to restore Test.csproj (in 7 ms).
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add or set

```xml
<ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>true</ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>
```

And try to install [Microsoft.Build.CentralPackageVersions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build.CentralPackageVersions/) into your project.

Comment: I do have <ManagePackageVersionsCentrally> set, but it still gets that error in Visual Studio.  What do you mean by installing Microsoft.Build.CentralPackageVersions into your project?  That has to be a nuget reference for each project using centralling referencing?

Comment: You can use [Directory.Build.targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019) to [import  CentralPackage packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-project-sdk?view=vs-2019) into each project. [The package](https://github.com/Microsoft/MSBuildSdks) contains some target/props files which are related to `CentralPackageVersionManagement`.

Comment: Ah ok, that would work with some effort, just a shame no built in way sounds like.  Is there an example anywhere of trying to do anything like this?

Comment: More docs are available at [https://github.com/microsoft/MSBuildSdks/tree/main/src/CentralPackageVersions](https://github.com/microsoft/MSBuildSdks/tree/main/src/CentralPackageVersions). You can put the `<Sdk Name="Microsoft.Build.CentralPackageVersions" Version="2.0.79" />` reference in a Directory.Build.targets file (beside Packages.props) so you don't have to reference that SDK explicitly in every project. This way you don't have to depend on NuGet Preview features like ManagePackageVersionsCentrally.